# Swift/Objective-C: How to call a view-controller-method from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, swift, iboutlet

Lets say I have a class called `FooController`. It will at some point in time call the method `bar(str: String)` owend by the second class `BarController`. `BarController` is a subclass of `NSViewController` and has an `IBOutlet`. This outlet is connected to a `NSButton`.

`bar` simply changes the text of the button to some string like "Example".

My first approach was to create a new instance of `BarController` and then calling the method.

```
var bc = BarController()
bc.bar("Example")
```

My problem is, that the new instance is not connectet to the interface and so the `IBOutlet` becomes `nil`.

```
func bar(str: String) {
    myButton.title = str // myButton is nil
}
```

Comment: I think you'd want to use delegates. Has BarController been pushed onto FooController? If so then BarController needs to be a delegate of FooController. When the function is called it will call a delegate function which will change the parent button's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Connect the button to a property in a class that is instantiated at your application launch, for example your AppDelegate. Let us say you create a property called aButton. 
---> Therefore you keep a track of your object

```
AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate
@property(weak) IBOutlet NSButton *aButton;
@end

AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppDelegate
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     BarController* controller = [BarController controllerForButton:aButton];
}
@end
```

2) When you create your BarController object, create a class method that would set a property _button to aButton. 
--> Therefore your objects knows the adress of your button.

```
BarController.h
@interface BarController
{
    NSButton *_button;
}
@end

BarController.m
@implementation BarController

+(BarController*)controllerForButton:(NSButton*)button{
    return[[BarController alloc] initWithButton:button];
}

-(void)initWithButton:(NSButton*)button{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _button = button;
    }
}
```